# SPSS: Fisher Exact not displaying result due to insufficient memory, despite more memory being allocated

Tags: memory, spss

**A Small bit of Background**
This question comes from a place of extreme ignorance and frustrated googling, so I'm sorry if my information is spotty or imprecise. My girlfriend is working with SPSS to analyze a survey she conducted for her veterinary bioscience thesis. She was running into errors during the execution of her data. She asked if I could help (being a software engineer) but I have zero experience with SPSS. I decided to turn to the stack overflow gods for help.

**What she is using**
She is running a crosstabulation on the following data:

[Crosstabulation from SPSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzyUV.png)

She was told to use Fisher Exact by her lecturers because a certain percentage of her results are below 5

Supposedly Fisher Exact is supposed to run after the crosstabulation, but the process gets interrupted with the following two errors:

[Error 1 - Time limit exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8zCl.png)
[Error 2 - Memory Exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj0pI.png)

**What we tried**
When I got my hands on it I immediately started googling up a storm. All posts for this particular issue said to use a syntax file and change the allocated memory using SET WORKSPACE = [Memory in KB]

Her dataset is incredibly small, only 207 rows, I reckon it would take very little memory to begin with, but for the sake of it I tried increasing the memory allocation to 300MB and later to 1GB, which I figured was a ridiculous volume of memory for such a small dataset. I figure it must be something else that's causing a loop or something, but I'm at my whit's end with the googling, and I can't imagine what's causing it, has anyone experienced such before? Even some idea as to what could be the cause? I hope the information in this thread isn't too vague! Thanks for any help!

Increasing Memory using SET WORKSPACE = [Memory in KB] to 300MB and 1GB so cannot be a memory issue for such a small dataset